# How do I `this->addChild(sprite)` from a method that is not my `bool HelloWorld::init()`

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to get into C++ with Eclipse & Cocos2d-x

I'm having trouble making a method that I can call from anywhere in the class.

My current WORKING code is:

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{if ( !LayerColor::initWithColor(ccc4(50, 180, 220, 255) )){
        return false;
    }

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create(
                                           "CloseNormal.png",
                                           "CloseSelected.png",
                                           CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback, this));

    closeItem->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width - closeItem->getContentSize().width/2 ,
                                origin.y + closeItem->getContentSize().height/2));

    //auto menu = Menu::create(closeItem, NULL);
    // menu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
    //this->addChild(menu, 1);

    auto label = LabelTTF::create("Kitty Katch", "Arial", 54);

    label->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2, origin.y + visibleSize.height - label->getContentSize().height));

    this->addChild(label, 1);

    // add "HelloWorld" splash screen"
    //auto sprite = Sprite::create("HelloWorld.png");
    //sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));
    //this->addChild(sprite, 0);

    CCSprite *theCloud = CCSprite::create("cloud.png");
    theCloud->setPosition(visibleSize.width/2,visibleSize.height/2);
    this->addChild(theCloud);

    //addACloud ();

    return true;
}
```

And that'll "Add a cloud" to my scene.

but I want to be able to call the void method instead:

```
void addACloud() {

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    CCSprite *theCloud = CCSprite::create("cloud.png");
    theCloud->setPosition(visibleSize.width/2,visibleSize.height/2);
    //this->addChild(theCloud); //(Causes error)
    HelloWorld->addChild(theCloud); // (error: Cannot use arrow operator on a type)

}
```

What am I doing wrong guys? thanks

Comment: Where is your method defined ? When you do call it, what happens ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `static` member function within your `HelloWorld` class. You would define something like:

```
class HelloWorld {
    /// ...
public:
    static void AddCloud( CCSprite* pCloud ) {
          /// Add cloud
    }
};
```

You will then be able to call this from outside the class using the following syntax:

```
HelloWorld::AddCloud( pCloud );
```

However, if you are trying to add the cloud to a data structure within the `HelloWorld` class, a `std::vector<CCSprite*>` for instance, then you will not be able to do this with a static member function and you will need to create a singleton. This is commonly done by putting `extern HelloWorld* g_pHelloWorld;` after your class definition, and then when initializing your program, putting: `g_pHelloWorld = new HelloWorld;` you can then use `g_pHelloWorld->AddCloud( pCloud )` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your addACloud() method need access to your HelloWorld object instance. In your original code
the call to

```
this->addChild(theCloud);
```

adds the CCSprite object instance, to the current (this->) HelloWorld object instance. If you want to be able to call

```
addACloud()
```

you need to make sure the HelloWorld object instance is available inside the function. This can either be done, by making the AddCloud() function a member function of your HelloWorld class:

```
class HelloWorld {
    // ...   
    public:
       void addACloud();
};
```

And then modifying your AddCloud implementation to

```
void HelloWorld::addACloud() {
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    CCSprite *theCloud = CCSprite::create("cloud.png");
    theCloud->setPosition(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2);
    this->addChild(theCloud);
}
```

Or alternatively if you want to be able to add clouds to different objects (maybe multiple instances of HelloWorld). You can leave AddCloud outside the class definition, but then need to pass the object instance, to which you want to add the clout as an argument:

```
AddCloud(HelloWorld *instance);
```

the addChild line in your implementation then becomes:

```
instance->addChild(theCloud);
```

It all boils down to having the object instance available inside your function. This happens implicitly in the first approach, by "this" being the object to add to. Or explicitly in the second case where you pass the object instance that you want to add the cloud to.

A theoretical third way is having a global, or static member, or some kind of singleton and making the object instance available through those methods. I would suggest using one of the first two.

Comment: This sounds close... I would go for the 2nd option, however there is something not working correctly. Can you Edit the code so it functions? The issue i ran into was the call "`addACloud (HelloWorld *instance);`" inline errors: 1) "use of undeclared identifier 'instance'" and 2) "'HelloWorld' does not refer to a value'. Then within the method the addChild line `instance->addChild(theCloud);` error: "Use of undeclared identifier 'instance'"

Comment: And after having now tested the first method, it doesn't like the use of 'this' in the method. Error: "Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function"

Comment: Ok, for "this->" to work, you need to declare the addAClound() function in your HelloWorld class header file, as shown and the implementation has then to be called HelloWorld::addAClound(). The second part was wrong in my example code.